# javascript three.js raycaster wont pick clones

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js

I'm simply trying to apply raycasting to objects placed on the screen, except theses models are clones of each other:

I got two boxes obj files cloned 5 times each in a loop and inserted into an array `MyboxArray[]`.

At runtime these boxes will have material added within another loop.
 example:`MyboxArray[i].children.material = whatever;`

then these boxes are added to the scene.

**The Issue:**
Once all the boxes are ready with textures  they are added to the `scene.add(MyArray[j])` also in a loop;

Below is where the issue is:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children,true);// or MyArray, myArray.children

        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {


           console.log( intersects[0].name);// returns undefined!
                       console.log( MyArray[0].name) // returns Good
         }
```

My problem is i cant interact with the item I have picked as it returns undefined, but I know it is there, generally if I just push items into an array it works, but these items are clones then pushed into an array so it doesn't want to catch them any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATED:** Im closer to the solution, the problem is  raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children,true);
Initilally i can do:    `raycaster.intersectObjects(MyArray[i].children);`//this will only pick 2 items objects...im needing to some how increment myArray..im guessing i have an array inside an array, any thoughts.

Comment: can you paste the code that duplicate your objects ?